# I need to make a circuit that activates an SOS buzzer, what are the components that I need?

Tags: power-electronics, buzzer

I have a project in my college that requires me to make an SOS (... --- ...) buzzer without any IC's, what are the possible components that I can use for the delay between the morse code signals? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would be tough without any IC.

Comment: Please be more specific about where you are stuck in the process of solving this project/task. Right now the question is too broad and cannot be answered. Is the sound to be played by a speaker, a buzzer which just needs a constant voltage and how did morse code suddenly become a part of this?

Comment: @EugeneSh. an oscilator can easily be made without integrated circuits (ICs).

Comment: @JakobHalskov Oscillator is insufficient here. It needs to be modulated to produce SOS

Comment: Can be done elecro-mechanically - rotating shaft with "bumps" which will open/close some contact.

Comment: How about Edison's invention: https://www.thehenryford.org/collections-and-research/digital-collections/artifact/226044/ :)

Comment: Just a normal piezo buzzer, the morse code is for translating S O S to morse code as long and short beeps @JakobHalskov

Comment: @EugeneSh. I just need it to be activated for one output - SOS when the switch is closed

Comment: @HoleWizard OK, this should be written in the question

Comment: --- ... --- How are you proposing to do this *without any IC's*?  *I just need it to be activated for one output*.  No you need to do timing and three distinct states.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Well, it *is* possible. For example one could think of a chain of relay-powered RC circuits, which will switch on each other (and off themselves) in order at different timings. Ugly, but doable.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I accept that *anything* is possible including a sharp stick and a ham radio operator, but OP has to start providing context.

Comment: will n555 IC do the job?

Comment: @HoleWizard. I thought no ICs!?!?

Comment: Use TR/FET, 1 2 3

Comment: well IC would result in a penalty

Comment: A single 555 probably won't help too much.

Comment: You need to clarify the restrictions on the project.  Then you need to state what you have done to complete the project.  And identify where you are stuck.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use a couple astable multivibrators and a ring counter with some diodes to create the pattern:

[image]

The circuit I used has 61 transistors, a bit more than 200 components, and is probably far from optimal, but easy to create with copy/paste.

[image]

Yours will, no doubt, be unique and different from this (deliberately unreadable) one.